# How to version the Language Neutral C++ assembly after MUIRCT has been executed

Tags: c++, windows-mui

We have a resource.dll that we are splitting into a Language Neutral Resource.dll and a Language specific Resource.dll.mui using the MUIRCT tool within the Windows SDK.

Unfortunately the LN file doesnt have any copyright, company, or version information (when viewed from Explorer\Properties\Details tab) and when dropping this assembly into VS it clearly doesnt have a version block.  Does anyone know how to correctly version a Language Neutral file post execution of the MUIRCT.exe?

Hope that makes sense, let me know if you require any more information.

Comment: It is a mutt of a tool.  Use the -q option so you can specify the resources, include the VERSION resource in the config file.

Comment: Thanks for the response Hans, I'll give that a go and get back to you - I agree it's not very intuitive!

Comment: Thanks Hans - this probably came down to my lack of understanding of how the process works under the hood - Our resourceconfig file had the Version resource specified for localizedResources but not the neutralResources.  Adding the typeNameID=#16 to the neutralResources has fixed my problem.  If you want to add an answer I'd be happy to accept it!

Comment: Go ahead and write the answer and accept it.  I didn't guess at the proper workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so finally managed to understand where I was going wrong - Thanks to Hans for pointing me in the direction of the resource configuration file.

Turns out that the resource configuration file can contain two sub elements - "localizedResources" which allows customization of which resource types go into the .mui file and also a "neutralResources" element which allows customization of which resources types to go into the Language Neutral file.

In our resource configuration file, the "neutralResources" element was empty - To fix my issue I simply had to add the correct resource typeNameID (which is #16 for the version resource) into this element!  The end result is the version block is in the LN file and all the properties\Details information are visible!